# Converting SQL with LEFT JOIN to Linq (Method Syntax)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

It's my first post here, so if I get anything wrong let me know and I'll fix it.

I'm struggling to convert a simple SQL statement with a left join, to a LINQ statement (Method syntax).  I cannot use Linquer since this is a .Net Core 5.0 MVC project.

Consider that I have two tables:

```
dbo.OrganisationChannel (Id, OrganisationId, ChannelId)
dbo.Channel (Id, ChannelName, ChannelUrl)
```

I want to show all channels that an organisation DOESN'T currently have.

Here is the **correct** SQL query

```
SELECT c.Id,  c.ChannelName, c.ChannelUrl
FROM dbo.Channel c
LEFT JOIN dbo.OrganisationChannel oc ON  c.Id = oc.ChannelId
WHERE oc.ChannelId IS NULL OR oc.OrganisationId <> 1
```

However, the corresponding `.GroupJoin` and `.SelectMany` is perplexing me.. I can't find the right place to add the WHERE clauses:

```
var groupItems = db.Channel
    .GroupJoin(
        db.OrganisationChannel,
        c => c.Id,
        oc => oc.ChannelId,
        (c, oc) => new { c, oc })
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.oc.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (chan, orgChan) => new
        {
            Id = chan.c.Id,
            ChannelName = chan.c.ChannelName,
            ChannelUrl = chan.c.ChannelUrl,
            IsActive = chan.c.IsActive,
        }
        );
```

I'd be grateful for any help here, thanks!

Si

Comment: Try following : var groupItems = db.Channel.Where(oc=> oc.ChannelId == DbNull.Value || oc.OrganisationId != 1)

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?
You can try: `var groupItems = db.Channel.Include(x=>x.OrganisationChannels).Where(x=>x.OrganisationChannels.ChannelId == null || x.OrganisationChannels.OrganisationId != 1`

Comment: Hi Kamalpreet - yes I am using EF Core within a .net Core 5.0 MVC project.

Comment: Hi jdweng - OrganisationId is part of the OrchanisationChannel table (the right side table), therefore not available within the oc context.  Also, would the .Where clause come before or after the GroupJoin?

Comment: Try my above example.

Comment: Hi Kamalpreet - hmmm ... there are two problems: (1) the ==null will always eval to false on an int and (2) x.OrganisationChannels.OrganisationId doesn't exist in the current context.  I must be missing something simple!

Comment: Can you update your question to include Entity classes for both Channel and OrganisationChannels?

Comment: public class Channel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }
        public string ChannelUrl { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OrganisationChannel> OrganisationChannels { get; set; } = new HashSet<OrganisationChannel>();
    }

Comment: `OrganisationChannel` Add this also please

Comment: public class OrganisationChannel { public int Id { get; set; } public int ChannelId { get; set; } public int OrganisationId { get; set; } public virtual Organisation { get; set; } public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; } }

Comment: I've an answer in the form of a query syntax solution - thanks for the attention thou Kamal! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method syntax with LEFT JOIN is a nightmare. If you really want method syntax install Reshaper and click "convert to method chain". But I do not recommend to do that - query become unmaintainable.

Your query is simple with query syntax

```
var query = 
   from c in db.Channel
   join oc in db.OrganisationChannel on c.Id equals oc.ChannelId into gj
   from oc in gj.DefaultIfempty()
   where (int?)oc.ChannelId == null || oc.OrganisationId != 1
   select new 
   {
       c.Id,
       c.ChannelName, 
       c.ChannelUrl
   };
```

Comment: Thanks Svyatoslav, this returns perfectly what is needed.  I appreciate the advice on Method Syntax as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LeftJoin` extension method :

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TResult, Ta, Tb, TKey>(this IQueryable<Ta> TableA, IEnumerable<Tb> TableB, Expression<Func<Ta, TKey>> outerKeySelector, Expression<Func<Tb, TKey>> innerKeySelector, Expression<Func<JoinIntermediate<Ta, Tb>, Tb, TResult>> resultSelector)
{
    return TableA.GroupJoin(TableB, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, (a, b) => new JoinIntermediate<Ta, Tb> { Value = a, ManyB = b }).SelectMany(intermediate => intermediate.ManyB.DefaultIfEmpty(), resultSelector);
}

public class JoinIntermediate<Ta, Tb>
{
    public Ta Value { get; set; }

    internal IEnumerable<Tb> ManyB { get; set; }
}
```

It's usage is similar to the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=net-5.0) extension method but will perform a left join instead of a regular join. Then you can add your call to the `Where` method right after the call to `LeftJoin`.

Comment: should give example. 
    NotificationEvents
    .Where(w => w.ID == 123)
    .LeftJoin(
            Events, 
            events => events.EventID, ev => ev.EventID, 
            (events, ev) => new { NotificationEvents = events, Events = ev }
    );

Comment: Hi Nalka - I like the LeftJoin simplisation, but I'm stuck at getting these into my table names (apologies, maybe need to look at this in the moring - its been a very long few days!)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query instead of lambda expressions

```
            from left in lefts
            join right in rights on left equals right.Left into leftRights
            from leftRight in leftRights.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { }
```

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh - please can you elaborate slightly, given my two table names (Channel, OrganisationChannel) and also the need to filter out where the OrganisationChannel.OrganisationId != 1

Answer (score 0):

check this url https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/left-outer-join-in-linq/

also my working code example:

```
 UserApiKeys
            .Where(w => w.AppID == AppID && w.IsActive)
            .Join(
                    UserApiApplications,
                    keys => keys.AppID,
                    apps => apps.AppID,
                    (keys, apps) => new { UserApiKeys = keys, UserApiApplications = apps}
                )
                .OrderByDescending(d => (d.UserApiKeys.ExpirationDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
                .Select(s => new {
                    ApiKey = s.UserApiKeys.ApiKey, 
                    IsActive = s.UserApiKeys.IsActive, 
                    SystemName = s.UserApiKeys.SystemName,
                    ExpirationDate = (s.UserApiKeys.ExpirationDate == null)
                                                                ? "Newer Expires"
                                                                : s.UserApiKeys.ExpirationDate.ToString(),
                    s.UserApiApplications
                })
                .ToList()
```

in addition, to refer @nalka post about extension method usage:

```
NotificationEvents
.Where(w => w.ID == 123)
.LeftJoin(
        Events, 
        events => events.EventID, ev => ev.EventID, 
        (events, ev) => new { NotificationEvents = events, Events = ev }
);
```

Comment: Thanks power Mouse - still struggling to work out where to place the Where Clause for the Id on the joined table.

Comment: you can add another Where condition at the end with w=>w.ev.XXX == "yyy" 
dont forget you have list of 2 linked objects.
in first example check OrderByDescending.. same where condition...

P.S. i would suggest to get Linqpad - it helps